# Bloomberg open API JAVA - how to store user data

Tags: java, trading, bloomberg

I am curious if there is a way to store some user data on my request which will come back to me on the returned data.  For example, I am sending several requests for let's say 3 different orders.  They might be for the same symbol, but depending on the order I will be getting different types of data.  Is there a way that I store the order ID on the outgoing message request and have it come back to me on the return?  I see there is a Session.sendRequest call where you can specify a requestLabel, but I don't see it coming back on the returned message so I'm not sure what this is for.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the correlation ID is exactly what is needed.  I can create a unique correlation ID for each order request based on the order ID and some unique string (for me, a count is sufficient).  Then I can parse out the order ID piece when it is returned.  I'm still not fully sure what requestLabel is for, but I don't think I need it for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be up to you and your app, not Bloomberg.  I'll bet Bloomberg is idempotent - it treats every request that comes in as if it's the first one ever.

The Session is a variable on your side that's created when a user logs in.  You'd create the label or some other unique tracking GUID and keep it in session.  Every request that user sends out during that Session would be associated with that session ID>

Comment: It's something that you create and add as the request label.  I'm assuming that Bloomberg will send it back to you.  Your client should only be getting their responses back from Bloomberg, so you'll be able to add them to session or, better yet, process and persist them.  I'm not sure why you need this.